# Repeat same option with multitoken

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Is it possible to repeat the same option with multitoken? For instance, is it possible from this line :

```
-t algo1 5 7 9 -t algo2 6 2
```

to obtain something like the following vector of vector?

```
  ___   ___
| ___ | ___ |
   |     |
   v     v
  ___   ___
 algo1 algo2
  ___   ___
   5     6
  ___   ___
   7     2
  ___   ___
   9
  ___
```

I tried:

```
value<vector<vector<string>>>()->multitoken()
```

but I have:

```
  ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___
| ___ | ___ | ___ | ___ | ___ | ___ | ___ |
   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
   v     v     v     v     v     v     v
  ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___
 algo1   5     7     9   algo2   6     2
  ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___   ___
```

What can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133523/c-boost-program-options-multiple-lists-of-arguments